# How to share complex objects in multiprocessing manager

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I know this question is being asked in many threads but so far I couldn't find proper solution.
Below is my code:

```
Class A:
   def init(self):
      self.b = B() 
Class B:
   def init(self):
       ....
```

In the main function

```
d = mp.Manager().dict()
p = mp.Pool(initializer=init function, initargs=[d])
```

d holds the objects created by multiple processes.
But when it runs, the variables inside the object are not shared between processes.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's one of the limitations of multiprocessing.  Those literally are separate processes with separate address spaces.  If you need to communicate between them, you need to use a queue or a socket.